# Why doesn't my custom validation run in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

This is my model:

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validate :progress_is_less_than_max 

  private
    def progress_is_less_than_max
      if progress > max
        errors.add(:progress, "should be less than max")
      end
    end

end
```

If I go into the console and do

```
some_user.goals.create! :name => 'test', :max => 10, :progress => 15, :unit => 'stuff'
```

it saves just fine, without any errors. What am I not doing right?

Comment: Does your User `has_many` goals? That is, do you explicitly specify the association with the `has_many` method in the User model?

Comment: Try with create (not create!)

Comment: @Dorian, create and save! throws the expected error. Thanks...and how confusing.

Comment: @maprihoda, yes it does.

Comment: try this : `private def progress_is_less_than_max if self.progress > self.max errors.add(:progress, "should be less than max") end end`

Comment: I believe the rule of thumb is that on model update type methods the ! version raises an exception and the non-! version returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not how you write a custom validator: your custom validator should inherit from `ActiveModel::EachValidator`.

See the bottom of this rails cast for an example of a customer validator: http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3?view=asciicast

Comment: No, his method should works, mine works : https://github.com/Ung-UTT/Site-etu-v9/blob/master/app/models/vote.rb

Answer (score 0):

@jaydel is correct in that .create will return an instance of the model (regardless of if it is saved in the database or not).

> Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

However, calling .save! on the .create'd model or calling .create! to begin with will raise an exception if validations fail.

> Creates an object just like ActiveRecord::Base.create but calls save! instead of save so an exception is raised if the record is invalid.

.save will run validations but returns false if they fail.

> By default, save always run validations. If any of them fail the action is cancelled and save returns false. However, if you supply :validate => false, validations are bypassed altogether. See ActiveRecord::Validations for more information.